# In asp.net resource.resx, can I reference another resource string , in same resex file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For reference, I am working on mvc3 application.
Sorry cant post image as I dont have those number of poits. Suppose I have String1 in my resource and I am defining string2, i have string2 content should be String1 + "my some text", is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question, it is similar, although not exactly what you want. However, I think the answer is the same.

Resource files do not have this kind of functionality, but you can do it in code though:

[Can one local .resx string reference another local .resx string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072706/can-one-local-resx-string-reference-another-local-resx-string)